# shortcuts in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

The strangest issue has just started cropping up in my python notebooks in VScode. I created a chatbot using the EXACT code from this ChatGPT tutorial: https://learn.deeplearning.ai/chatgpt-prompt-eng/lesson/8/chatbot

When I get to the part of the code below I'm greeted by the chatbot, but when I type my responses anytime I type certain letters it's like I'm activating VSCODE shortcuts. The letter 'a' opens a new cell (and skips the cursor out of the text box). The letter 'o' collapses the output of the cell where the text box is, and 'f' opens the find text window that you normally open with 'command f'. Why are these keystrokes suddenly triggering shortcuts?

````
button_conversation = pn.widgets.Button(name="Chat!")

interactive_conversation = pn.bind(collect_messages, button_conversation)



pn.extension(scroll=True)

dashboard = pn.Column(
    interactive_conversation,
    inp,
    pn.Row(button_conversation)
)
dashboard```
````

Comment: use the key bind debug to see what happens when you press a key

Comment: Are you working in a .ipynb file or a .py file?

Comment: Your link takes to me to a log in page. Can you include the relevant info in the question?

Comment: What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.

Comment: This is what happened when I tried to run the troubleshoot your keybindings page. There is a lot of display (too much to copy paste), but here is what looks relevant:

Comment: 2023-08-24 10:43:36.120 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-08-24 10:43:36.120 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2023-08-24 10:43:36.120 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [meta], code: MetaLeft, keyCode: 91, key: Meta
2023-08-24 10:43:36.120 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [meta], code: MetaLeft, keyCode: 57 ('Meta')
2023-08-24 10:43:36.121 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.

Comment: 2023-08-24 10:43:38.038 [error] Error: The editor could not be opened because the file was not found.

Comment: 2023-08-24 10:44:29.098 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-08-24 10:44:29.119 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2023-08-24 10:44:29.119 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [meta], code: MetaLeft, keyCode: 91, key: Meta
2023-08-24 10:44:29.119 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [meta], code: MetaLeft, keyCode: 57 ('Meta')
2023-08-24 10:44:29.119 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.

Comment: Let me know if you need more than that. The part that reads, "2023-08-24 10:43:38.038 [error] Error: The editor could not be opened because the file was not found." seems most relevant.

Comment: It's an .ipynb file.